# Websocket handshake status 200 exception

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, autobahn

This is my client:

```
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("wss://127.0.0.1:8080",
                       sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE, "check_hostname": False, "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1})
        data = json.dumps({"api_command":"sensor_data","session_id":session_id})
        ws.send(data)
```

And this is my server:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    txaio.start_logging(level='debug')

    # SSL server context: load server key and certificate
    # We use this for both WS and Web!
    contextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('keys/server.key',
                                                      'keys/server.crt')

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"wss://127.0.0.1:9000")
    # by default, allowedOrigins is "*" and will work fine out of the
    # box, but we can do better and be more-explicit about what we
    # allow. We are serving the Web content on 8080, but our WebSocket
    # listener is on 9000 so the Origin sent by the browser will be
    # from port 8080...
    factory.setProtocolOptions(
        allowedOrigins=[
            "https://127.0.0.1:8080",
            "https://localhost:8080",
        ]
    )

    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    listenWS(factory, contextFactory)

    webdir = File(".")
    webdir.contentTypes['.crt'] = 'application/x-x509-ca-cert'
    web = Site(webdir)
    reactor.listenSSL(8080, web, contextFactory)
    #reactor.listenTCP(8080, web)

reactor.run()
```

When I run the client, the following error is thrown in the client

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200
```

While on the server:

```
2017-08-23T16:08:58+0300 WebSocketServerFactory (TLS) starting on 9000
2017-08-23T16:08:58+0300 Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketServerFactory object at 0x04AADAF0>
2017-08-23T16:08:58+0300 Site (TLS) starting on 8080
2017-08-23T16:08:58+0300 Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x04ACD770>
2017-08-23T16:09:32+0300 "127.0.0.1" - - [23/Aug/2017:13:09:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2042 "-" "-"
```

I don't understand what the problem is. My server is from this example https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls. If I use a client like the one shown in that example, it connects just fine. I can't connect using the simple websocket library though.

The exception is thrown at `create_connection` of the websocket client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
ws = create_connection(
    "wss://127.0.0.1:8080",
    sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE, 
            "check_hostname": False, 
            "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
    }
)
```

use

```
ws = create_connection(
    "ws://127.0.0.1:8080",
    sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE, 
            "check_hostname": False, 
            "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1}
)
```

It should be 'ws' not 'wss'.

You can use [websocket-server](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server), if you need more help let me know

Comment: this throws `websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.`

Comment: whats server you running. Restart your server